# Как задать путь до my computer?

Tags: windows, php

Помогите, люди добрые, у меня есть скрипт php, мне надо показать содержимое моего компьютера в браузере, на windows, но я не знаю, как указать путь до my computer. Вот мой скрипт.

```
<?php
$dir = "uploads/"; // задаём имя директории
if (is_dir($dir)) { // проверяем наличие директории
    echo $dir . ' - директория существует;<br>';
    $files = scandir($dir); // сканируем (получаем массив файлов)
    array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
    array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($files); $i++)
        echo '-файл: <a href="' . $dir . $files[$i] . '" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">' . $files[$i] . '</a>;<br>'; //выводим все файлы
} else
    echo $dir . ' -такой директории нет.<br>';
?>
```

Comment: А зачем путь до "Мой компьютер"? на сколько я знаю, такого пути и нет. Существуют диски, по которым можно пройтись последовательно. C: , D: , E: и так далее. И еще вопрос, PHP крутится на на Windows?

Comment: php крутится на локальном сервере,у меня такая задача показать содержимое my computer в браузере

Comment: my_computer в Windows это графическое приложение. Вряд ли Вам удастся прочитать его вывод в php

Comment: @avp, нужен всего-то доступ к реестру) Диски можно через `is_dir` проверить. Но т.к. с реестром на php я не работал, пока пас)

Comment: Делаешь BAT-файл,который берет с реестра все, что тебе нужно. Потом вызываеш этот батник со своего скрипта и парсишь его вывод консольный.
Через Ж конечно, но по другому не знаю как :)